# C++ (Builder XE7) enum type property misterious behaviour

Tags: properties, enums, c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I'm not an expert in C++ but need to update an old project to Embarcadero C++ Builder XE7.

This code does not compile (the fpFixed line):

```
#include <System.UITypes.hpp>
...
NewText->Font->Pitch = fpFixed;
```

Where Pitch is:

```
__property System::Uitypes::TFontPitch Pitch = {read=GetPitch, write=SetPitch, default=0};
void __fastcall SetPitch(const System::Uitypes::TFontPitch Value);
```

and

```
enum class DECLSPEC_DENUM TFontPitch : unsigned char { fpDefault, fpVariable, fpFixed };
```

Error: "E2451 Undefined symbol 'fpFixed'"

Another two attempts:

```
NewText->Font->Pitch = TFontPitch.fpFixed;
NewText->Font->Pitch = System::Uitypes::TFontPitch.fpFixed;
```

Error for both: E2108 Improper use of typedef 'TFontPitch'

But this - strangely - compiles, with no warning:

```
System::Uitypes::TFontPitch( fpFixed );   // yes,no assignments here just an unused value
NewText->Font->Pitch = fpFixed;
```

What is the explanation of this and am I doing something wrong here? Just came to this "solution" by trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NewText->Font->Pitch = TFontPitch.fpFixed;
>   NewText->Font->Pitch = System::Uitypes::TFontPitch.fpFixed;

You were on the right track with this, but you used the wrong syntax.  Use `::` instead of `.`:

```
NewText->Font->Pitch = TFontPitch::fpFixed;
NewText->Font->Pitch = System::Uitypes::TFontPitch::fpFixed;
```

This is documented in Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[Strongly Typed Enums (C++0x)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Strongly_Typed_Enums_(C++0x))